# Why isn't LIMIT working here?

Tags: mysql, php

I commented out the LIMIT statement because it's not working. All selected rows are *always* returned, no matter what.

Code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT riderUid AS  `rider`, ( ";
 $sql .= "SELECT SUM( mileage ) ";
 $sql .= "FROM  `mileage` ";

 if (isset($ytd) && $ytd == 1) {
     $sql .= "WHERE riderUid =  `rider` AND $year = YEAR(CURDATE()) ";
     $title = "Year-to-date";
 } else {
     $sql .= "WHERE riderUid = `rider` AND YEAR(rideDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(rideDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ";
     $title = "This month";
 }

 $sql .= "ORDER BY mileage DESC ";
 //$sql .= "LIMIT 5 ";
 $sql .= ") AS  `miles` ";
 $sql .= "FROM  `mileage` ";
 $sql .= "GROUP BY riderUid ";
 $sql .= "ORDER BY  `miles`  DESC";
```

I tried the statement in a couple other locations, without success.

result of `echo $sql;` with the LIMIT statement back in:

```
SELECT riderUid AS `rider`, 
( SELECT SUM( mileage ) FROM `mileage` 
WHERE riderUid = `rider` AND 
YEAR(rideDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND 
MONTH(rideDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY mileage DESC 
LIMIT 5)
AS `miles` FROM `mileage` 
GROUP BY riderUid 
ORDER BY `miles` DESC
```

**Addendum**

Here's the table structure:

[image]

Each row represents one rider/ride (riderUid/rideID).

What I want to do is to sum each rider's mileage then return an ordered set of rows from most to least miles per rider (monthly or YTD).

A version of this would limit it to just the top `n` riders, which would be for a portable widget (one that could go on any page).

Currently I iterate through the rows and get the usernames, etc. from other tables. Ideally I'd like to do a JOIN in this query to get those, but I'm not a DBA and not skilled enough to do that. What I have here I harvested from SO, with a few modifications, and if anybody can suggest a better way to do it I'd be most grateful.

Comment: What code do you *think* you're generating with this? And how sure are you? Have you tested the code you *think* you're generating? Did it show the same result, and if so -- why aren't you just asking about that instead of PHP string concatenation?

Comment: Please `echo $sql;` so we can discuss the SQL more easily.

Comment: @RickJames: Added the echo.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: The code works fine except for the LIMIT statement, which has no effect.

Comment: The expected effect of `LIMIT whatever` in the specific place in this query is exactly that, no effect. It would help if you tell us what the query is supposed to do. Then someone could offer a different query.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Please see above. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: OK - for starters get rid of the PHP! It's irrelevant here - no offence, but we're database people, not PHP/Perl/whatever coders! You've shown us the SQL - that's good. Now, in place of your graphic (**[bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)**), please paste (formatted) the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mileage\G` instead. **Even** better, give us your DDL (`CREATE TABLE mileage (f1 dt1...);`) and some sample data, and give us your DML (`INSERT INTO mileage VALUES (....);`) - (provide db-fiddle?). Then give us the result you require **and** the logic you used to get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery has an aggregate function (`SUM`) and no `GROUP BY`. This is an implicit `GROUP BY` and all the rows of the table are grouped into a single group / row. As a result the `LIMIT` has no effect there. You could have `LIMIT 1` or `LIMIT 5` or `LIMIT 5000000` or no `LIMIT` at all. The result is the same (only `LIMIT 0` would make a difference).

If you want:

- for a specific month, the sum of mileage per rider, and then keep the top 5 riders according to this sum, The `LIMIT` should be applied in the main query or - since it is not needed - have no subquery at all:

  ```
  SELECT riderUid AS rider, 
         SUM(mileage) AS miles
  FROM mileage
  WHERE YEAR(rideDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(rideDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
  GROUP BY riderUid 
  ORDER BY miles DESC 
  LIMIT 5 ;
  ```

The date condition (current month) could also be rewritten, avoiding applying functions on the date/timestamp column so indexes can be used:

```
WHERE LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH   -- first day of month
        <= rideDate 
  AND      rideDate 
             <  LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY       -- first day of next month
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thanks. And thanks for being patient with a SQL noob.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect this to do

```
SELECT sum(v)
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS v UNION SELECT 2)
  AS t;
```

What about,

```
SELECT sum(v)
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS v UNION SELECT 2 )
  AS t
LIMIT 1;
```

Hint they're the same. `LIMIT` runs *after* the aggregate. Not sure where MySQL documents this, but PostgreSQL -- which has better documentation -- does so [under `SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html).

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that I get no result at all.

Comment: What does that mean "no result at all?

Comment: No rows returned. At all.

Comment: @Robusto lol, yea, ok.... may want to look at that.

Comment: or, run your tests on dbfiddle or sqlfiddle.